# Default search field in SOlr 4.10

Tags: solr

All:

All I want to know is which fields are defaut for searching in Solr 4.10 and how to config them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make the **field** default using **df field** in your **requestHandler** of the **solrconfig.xml**
**df** denotes - **default** field
Try this

```
<str name="df">term</str>
```